# Why is there a large dip in the spectral distribution of sunlight at 760 nm?

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science

I'm doing research with the spectral distribution of sunlight and I noticed that there was a large dip in wavelength at 760 nm. I was wondering if anyone knew why that was! My thoughts were that there was something in the atmosphere that absorbed that specific wavelength of light (Maybe nitrogen or O2 because of how large the drop is). Could anyone help me out? If you could explain the other dips as well, that would be sweet!

Comment: [The graph at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#/media/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg) labels these dips. Is one of them yours?

Comment: Look in to [Fraunhofer lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_lines). At 760 nanometers is an $\mathrm{O}_2$ absorption band (see Fraunhofer line labeled "A").

Comment: A picture might be helpful but it's most probably O$_2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is the transition from the triplet ground state $^3\Sigma_g$ of oxygen (two parallel spins in the $\pi$-orbitals) to the singlet sigma excited state $^1\Sigma_g$.